# MOSFET gate capacitance near \$V_{gs,th}\$ (miller plateau)?

Tags: mosfet, capacitance, gate-driving

I have trouble inferring a realistic value of the gate capacitance for when a MOSFET is used near its turn-on voltage, i.e. not as a switch but as a linear regulator. It's important to find a meaningful gate capacitance value for the regulation stage that drives the MOSFET gate.

For example consider the [Rohm RQ3E080GNTB](https://fscdn.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/discrete/transistor/mosfet/rq3e080gntb-e.pdf) . Figure 16 and Figure 18 are the relevant Figures I suppose (attached at the bottom).

When in regulation, the \$V_{gs}\$ is constantly near the miller region. According to Figure 18 below, the gate capacitance would be *infinite* in this region, which obviously makes no sense. Figure 16, in contrast, gives absolutely no indication of any substantial modification of the gate capacitance.

I also performed an LTspice sim with a (spec-wise) similar MOSFET, the IRFML8244. I charged the gate with a low constant current and indeed, the capacitance seems to be at least an order of magnitude increased. Does that mean that a gate capacitance of ~10 nF would be a more reasonable value for the drive circuitry of the MOSFET gate ?

[image][image]

Comment: It's not infinite, but it's Ciss + (Crss * voltage gain) so you need to know the voltage gain. As you can see, there's nothing untoward in Crss; the plateau is simply the result of sudden Vds change (rail to rail in a typical switching application) coupled to gate via Crss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *According to Figure 18 below, the gate capacitance would be infinite
> in this region, which obviously makes no sense.*

I think you are misinterpreting what *"seems like"* a sudden change in gate-source capacitance when, it is in fact, the effect of negative feedback via the drain-gate capacitance creating the appearance of a virtual ground on the gate. It's just like what happens with negative feedback on op-amps; the output change due to a small change on the input forces the input to remain at (near-enough) a constant value.

It's actually plain ordinary negative feedback and, it appears much worse when the change in drain voltage is bigger because, it produces the appearance of \$C_{DG}\$ being much bigger than it is.

> *Figure 16, in contrast, gives absolutely no indication of any
> substantial modification of the gate capacitance.*

You can reasonably rely on figure 16's information of course. Gate capacitance is measured with drain and source held at a constant voltage hence, no appearance of negative feedback.

Comment: That means, for a usual linear regulator, where the voltages at drain and source are almost constant, there is no plateau and the Qgate v Vgate is almost linear at a value given by Fig 16 ?

Comment: @tobalt yes, that would be the case.